# Rails how to cache partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, partial

I'm using a `render partial: 'fragment', locals:{obj:item}` for every row in table. 
It takes long time to process the whole page.

Is there a way to save all fragments for each item at first loading and don't render them again each time during the server works?

**UPDATED**

```
card/index.html.haml
%table 
  =render partial: 'card/card', collection: @cards, cached: true

card/_card.html.haml
-cache card do
  %tr=card.title

card_controller.rb
def index
  @cards = Card.order(:name)
end
```

**SOLVED**

Cached started to work after I add to development.rb:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }
```

Comment: Please checkout https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/09/rails-5-makes-partial-redering-from-cache-substantially-faster.html

Comment: I have implement it, but I have already seen row `Rendered collection of card/_card.html.haml [0 / 163 cache hits] (2522.1ms)`

I used `=render partial: 'card/card', collection: @cards, cached: true` in index file and `-cache card do...` in partial _card.html.haml

Also I have setted `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` in development.rb env file

Myabe I need any other configure?

Comment: can you update your question with your controller and partial code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In default configuration rails does not have caching enabled/configured in development.
Starting with rails 5 you can `touch tmp/caching-dev.txt` or `rm tmp/caching-dev.txt` and restart server to toggle it (for earlier versions you can backport this to your app, see [config/development.rb of 5.2.1](https://github.com/railsdiff/api/blob/master/generated/v5.2.1/config/environments/development.rb#L17)).

Note that you also have to configure production environment and have a cache backend - it may be wasteful to have separate cache in each worker. Thus redis/memcached should be handy.

Then as a rule of thumb - it's better to use the same cache store and similar configuration in development, because cache store has non-zero latency and sometimes it can be faster not to cache something and you want your development env to be closer to production.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can run `rails dev:cache` to toggle caching.